# How to convert DateTime to MSSQL integer in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have to use a web service, where one of the parameters is date represented as a 5-digit number like this:

```
DATETIME   INT
---------  ----
1/1/2009   39814
2/1/2009   39845
3/1/2009   39873
4/1/2009   39904
```

After googeling this I found out that this is MS-SQL representation. Do you guys have any idea how to make this integer in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Knowing that the dates being passed in from MS-SQL are always formatted the same, I would create a method in which you create substrings of the dates/times and then rebuild them as ints in java. As peter.petrov mentioned, there is no standard method of keeping dates/times. It is very program specific and you will most likely need to make a method of your own to do this. Check out [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on how to format dates/times in java.

Comment: That's not an MS SQL representation.  A MS SQL `datetime` cast as `int` will be the number of days since 1900-01-01.  What you are dealing with is how MS Excel stores dates, which is the number of days since 1899-12-30.

Comment: I see, thanks Anon, so I'll have to compute the number of days since that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That integer is the number of days since 1899-12-30.  This is how Microsoft *Excel* stores dates, not SQL Server.

```
--integer to date
SELECT DATEADD(day,@integer,'1999-12-30')

--date to integer
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'1999-12-30',@date)
```